# How can I control the airflow in a car by open or closed window configuration?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, drag, flow, aerodynamics

What car window configuration will let air in by me and make / let it exit away from me. I have a large divider between front and back seats that covers much, but not all the plane between. People in back often don't want windows open much.  Basically I want all air in car to exit away from me and not circulate past my face. I don't care if air enters by me, I just don't want any coming to me from elsewhere in the car or coming back to me.

Comment: Trial and error is usually the best way to find what is most comfortable to you without disturbing your passengers.

Comment: If this is a Covid-19 precaution, just wear a good mask.  They work.

Comment: Neither of these comments really answered the question, is there a specific forum I could ask this question in?  I don't have a wind tunnel and colored smoke handy.